# Task Fails to Run

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I wrote a small utility to read large text files and search for lines that contain a search term.  I'm using this as an opportunity to learn TPL Dataflow.

The code works fine, unless the search term is near the very end of the file.  In that case, the `uiResult` action block does not get called *unless* there is a breakpoint in it.

My understanding is that data is posted to `uiResult` from `searcher`, *after* which `searcher` becomes complete (it has processed its last block of data).  Since data has been posted to `uiResult` it should not become complete until after that data is processed.

**Question**

Why is it that `uiResult` becomes complete even though data is posted to it (unless a breakpoint was set in `uiResult`)?

**Code**

Here's the relevant code, as trimmed back as possible:

```
ActionBlock<LineInfo> uiResult = new ActionBlock<LineInfo>(li =>
    {
        // If match found near end of file, the following line only runs
        // if a breakpoint is set on it:
        if (results != null) results.Add(li);
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
        CancellationToken = cancelSource.Token,
        TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    });

BatchBlock<LineInfo> batcher = new BatchBlock<LineInfo>(5000); 

ActionBlock<LineInfo[]> searcher = new ActionBlock<LineInfo[]>(lines =>
    {
        foreach (LineInfo li in lines)
        {
            if (li.TextOfLine.Contains(searchTerm))
            {
                uiResult.Post(li);
            }
        }
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
        CancellationToken = cancelSource.Token
    });

batcher.LinkTo(searcher);

batcher.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)searcher).Fault(t.Exception);
    else searcher.Complete();

    if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)uiResult).Fault(t.Exception);
    else uiResult.Complete();
});

Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null && cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                batcher.Post(new LineInfo() { LineNumber = lineNumber, OffsetOfLine = offset, TextOfLine = line });
            }

            batcher.Complete();
            try
            {
                searcher.Completion.Wait();
                uiResult.Completion.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                TaskCanceledException taskCancelled = ae.InnerException as TaskCanceledException;
                if (taskCancelled != null)
                {
                    // Swallow the Exception if is just a user cancellation
                    throw;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                signalDone();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you really saying that setting a breakpoint changes the behavior? That's very suspicious.

Comment: @svick: Yes, I can consistently reproduce that behavior.  Feels like there is a thread timing issue that is altered by the breakpoint.  My understanding though is that the code as written should be deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is non-deterministic because of the way you're handling completion. A possible sequence of events is this:

1. The `Task` processes the whole file and calls `Complete()` on `batcher`.
2. `batcher` processes the last batch, sends it to `searcher` and completes.
3. The continuation is executed, which calls `Complete()` on both `searcher` and `uiResult`.
4. Since `uiResult` has no work to do, it completes.
5. `searcher` processes the last batch, trying to send each result to `uiResult`. But `uiResult` is already completed, so it rejects everything. This means `Post()` returns `false`, but you're not checking for that.

So the problem is that you're trying to send something to a block that already completed, which doesn't work.

The solution is to call `Complete()` on a block only after the block before it completes (i.e. its `Completion` completes). Probably the easiest way to do that is to use [`PropagateCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion) with `LinkTo()`.

Comment: I see the problem now that you point it out, but don't understand the solution.  The documentation for PropagateCompletion is a little light.  How would I restructure the code around `batcher.Completion.ContinueWith` to handle faulting correctly but to wait for `searcher` and `uiResult` to finish existing work?

Comment: @EricJ. Like I said, don't use `ContinueWith()`, but use `PropagateCompletion` instead. That will complete or fault the following block properly when it's time. If you want to keep using `COntinueWith()`, you would need two continuations: one for `batcher.Completion` that completes `searcher` and another for `searcher.Completion` that completes `uiResult`.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my problem.  To be sure I understand... in my case `searcher` and `uiResult` are both `ActionBlock<T>`s, so I cannot use LinkTo (neither implements `IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>`).  I did solve this by using `PropogateCompletion` with the batcher->searcher link.  Could I just as well have changed `searcher` to a `TransformManyBlock<T>` linked to `uiResult` and returned either an empty enumeration (for lines not matching the search) or an enumeration of 1 element (for lines that do match)?

Comment: @EricJ. Right, I didn't realize that. `TransformManyBlock` would work, either without `batcher` the way you describe, or with it returning collection of all elements that matched. Another way to do filtering is to use an overload of `LinkTo()` with predicate, but that requires another block that does nothing as a sink for items that didn't match (you can use [`NullTarget()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx) for that).

Comment: I saw the option of providing multiple LinkTo in another of your answers, but don't like that in this case because it puts the line matching logic in the predicate itself.  Thanks again for your help.  I understand Dataflow better now.